# How to remove BOM from UTF-8 CSV file imported into SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to remove the BOM from the imported table off a csv file. Would any one know where I could apply the "utf-8-sig" to my code to successfully do this.

I've tried changing the filename.encode("utf-8") to filename.encode("utf-8-sig") but it doesn't seem to change anything. I'm not sure I'm understanding how encoding something works honestly.

'''
class csvrd(object):

```
def csvFile(self):

    self.readFile('Tuning_Acronyms.csv')

def readFile(self, filename):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Actions (Acronym TEXT, Detail TEXT, Tuple INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
    filename.encode('utf-8-sig')
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM Actions")

    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for field in reader:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Actions VALUES (?,?,NULL);", field)
    cur.execute(("Update Actions SET Tuple = Tuple - 1 WHERE Tuple > 0 "))


    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

'''

My results always end up with the first row starting with 'ï»¿'

Example

['ï»¿NT', 'No Tuning']

I would like to remove 'ï»¿' and a possible explanation of the relations of BOMS and encoding.

Anything helps. :)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Its an excel file saved as "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)(*.csv)" file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

I applied the encoding to the Open() statement.

```
class csvrd(object):
    # To be combined into connect()

    def csvFile(self):

        self.readFile('Acronyms.csv')

    def readFile(self, filename):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Actions (Acronym TEXT, Detail TEXT, Tuple INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
        print(filename)
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM Actions")
        with open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for field in reader:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO Actions VALUES (?,?,NULL);", field)
        cur.execute(("Update Actions SET Tuple = Tuple - 1 WHERE Tuple > 0 "))


        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```